# Search Active Directory for all Usernames associated with email address

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have a method that searches Active Directory for Usernames based on an email address. There are cases where there may be multiple usernames for a given email address, and I'm trying to capture those. I have rewritten my method, but can't seem to get the syntax quite right. the issue is this line I believe.

```
foreach (Object myObject in result.Properties[property])
```

thanks,

Jason

```
private String FindNameByEmail(string emailAddress)
{
    DirectoryEntry entry = GetDirectoryEntry();
    emailAddress = txtEmailID.Text;

    DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
    search.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=*)(mail=" + emailAddress + "))";

    string[] properties = new string[] { "SAMAccountName" };
    foreach (String property in properties)
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add(property);
    SearchResultCollection result = search.FindAll();

    if (result != null)
    {
        foreach (String property in properties)
           foreach (Object myObject in result.Properties[property])
                lblUserName.Text = myObject.ToString();
        return "User Found";
    }
    else
    {
        lblStatus.Text = "user does not exist";
        return "User Does Not Exist";
    }
}
```

Comment: `GetDirectoryEntry()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** Changed it to output to a list of strings

Here we go:

```
List<string> usernames = new List<string>();
if (result != null) 
{
     foreach (SearchResult sr in result)
     {
         usernames.Add((string)sr.Properties["SAMAccountName"][0]);
     }
}
listBox1.DataSource = usernames; //Where listbox is declared in your markup
listBox1.DataBind();
```

Just Replace your if (result != null) logic with myne

Comment: thank you for your reply. it is now returning the last username in active directory that is associated with the email address. I only have 6 users, and 4 are are associated with the email.

Comment: when i run debug, and step through the results, I can see each username that i'm expecting. but only the last one is being written out.

Comment: this will write all of the users out on the screen Response.Write(users + "<br />");

Comment: @Jason, That is because you are writing it to the listbox, change it to output it to a list of some sort, I will update my code accordingly

Comment: thanks again for the help. I am getting a error that The best overloaded method match for System.Collections.Generic.List<string>.Add(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Pleasure, Fixed, it needed typecasting from object to string