# Is it possible to find the domain login based on the email address in the Active Directory?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I have an email address and based on it, I need to find the user's domain login.  I've seen Outlook do it, so I know it's possible.

How does one do it in .NET?

Comment: My guess is a smart DirectoryService query against the AD

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search Active Directory for all Usernames associated with email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665407/search-active-directory-for-all-usernames-associated-with-email-address)